# Show that for any non-zero ploynomial $q(x)$ of a degree less than $n$ that the vector $AE_1$ is non-zero.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

Suppose I have the square matrix
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots &a_{1} \\
        1 & 0 & 0 &\cdots &a_{2} \\
        0 & 1 & 0 &\cdots &a_{3} \\
        \vdots & \vdots &\vdots& \ddots&\vdots\\ 
        0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots&a_{n} \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
How do I show that for any non-zero ploynomial $q(x)$ of a degree less than $n$ that the vector
$$
q(A)
       \begin{pmatrix}
        1\\
        0\\
        0 \\
        \vdots\\ 
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
is non-zero. So I have to show that the first column vector of $q(A)$ does not consist of only 0 elements. Thankful for help

Comment: **Hint:** What is $A^k (1,0,\dots,0)^T$ for each $k = 0,1,\dots,n-1$?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Oh: $A^k(1,0,…,0)^T $ is just a vector of zeros with a one on index $k+1$. Then the problem is easy, thanks!